# How to dismiss AlertDialog and DropDownButton on same time when click anywhere outside of the AlertDialog

Tags: flutter

I have created a flutter web application. My screen has AlertDialog and in that dialogue, there is a DropDownButton Widget. My requirement is, when I open the AlertDialog and Tap on the DropDownButton then if I click anywhere outside the AlertDialog the Dialog and the DropDownButton should dismiss at the same time.

Please help me on this if there are any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the behavior you described in your Flutter web application, you can use the PopupMenuButton widget combined with an overlay. The overlay will capture taps outside the AlertDialog and dismiss it along with the DropDownButton. Here's a step-by-step guide on how to implement this:

Import the required packages:
Make sure you have the flutter and flutter/material.dart packages imported in your Dart file.

Use a StatefulWidget:
Since you want to handle the state changes when the AlertDialog is shown or dismissed, use a StatefulWidget for your main widget.

Create a function to show the AlertDialog:
In the StatefulWidget's state, create a function to show the AlertDialog when needed. You can use the showMenu function to display a PopupMenuButton.

Create an overlay:
Use a GestureDetector wrapped inside a Stack to create an overlay that covers the entire screen and captures taps outside the AlertDialog.

Here's a sample code snippet to demonstrate the implementation:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  GlobalKey _key = GlobalKey();

  // Function to show the AlertDialog (DropDownButton in this case)
  void _showDropDownMenu() {
    final RenderBox renderBox = _key.currentContext.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    final position = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);

    showMenu(
      context: context,
      position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(
        position.dx,
        position.dy,
        position.dx + renderBox.size.width,
        position.dy + renderBox.size.height,
      ),
      items: [
        PopupMenuItem(
          child: Text('Option 1'),
          value: 1,
        ),
        PopupMenuItem(
          child: Text('Option 2'),
          value: 2,
        ),
        // Add more options if needed
      ],
      elevation: 8.0,
    ).then((selectedValue) {
      // Handle the selected value here if needed
      if (selectedValue != null) {
        print('Selected value: $selectedValue');
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Flutter Web Dialog Example')),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          key: _key,
          onPressed: () {
            // Call the function to show the AlertDialog
            _showDropDownMenu();
          },
          child: Text('Open Dialog'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In this example, tapping outside the AlertDialog will dismiss both the AlertDialog and the DropDownButton. When you click the "Open Dialog" button, it will open the DropDownButton (PopupMenuButton) on top of the screen, and the GestureDetector in the background will capture taps outside the DropDownButton and dismiss it.